# Python list comprehension on fetchall() results?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, list

So I have run a query in python and get a list of results, now in these results there can/are multiple entries on the same person for example:

```
[
    ["1", "someone", "cool", "RO",  "AC", "SKST", "yes", "2/24/2017 0:00", "2/24/2017 10:51"],
    ["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/26/2015 15:54", "1/26/2015 15:54"],
    ["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "NO", "6/29/2015 0:00", "6/29/2015 12:36"],
    ["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "yes", "8/31/2017 0:00", "8/31/2017 13:12"],
    ["62", "again", "someoneelse", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/30/2017 0:00", "1/30/2017 13:49"],
    etc...
]
```

So looking at that data we can see that person with id 102 has multiple entries and I would like to filter this list so we only get one entry per person and have it be the most recent using the last date field.

So for person id# 102 we would drop all other entries and keep only the newest one dated: 8/31/2017 13:12

I'm new to python so I'm not sure how do this, thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you not just modify your query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*want hassle free code and easy to grasp*

```
    m = [
["1", "someone", "cool", "RO",  "AC", "SKST", "yes", "2/24/2017 0:00", "2/24/2017 10:51"],
["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/26/2015 15:54", "1/26/2015 15:54"],
["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "NO", "6/29/2015 0:00", "6/29/2015 12:36"],
["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "yes", "8/31/2017 0:00", "8/31/2017 13:12"],
["62", "again", "someoneelse", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/30/2017 0:00", "1/30/2017 13:49"],

]
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
list1 = sorted(m, key= lambda x:(x[0],x[8]),reverse = True)
out= [i for i in unique_everseen(list1,key= lambda x:x[0])]
```

Comment: what is `more_itertools`? It is not part of the Python standard library?

Comment: do pip install  more_itertools

Comment: interesting library. I will have to read more about. However, since you are using a third party module in your answer, you should write an explanation for how the method you are using from `more_itertools` works.

Comment: there are bunch of very cool functions extending the power of itertools python standard library you can find it here https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: plz vote if you liked this i spent a lot of time writting this and sharing with you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `dateutils` in Python3:

```
import itertools
s = [
["1", "someone", "cool", "RO",  "AC", "SKST", "yes", "2/24/2017 0:00", "2/24/2017 10:51"],
["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/26/2015 15:54", "1/26/2015 15:54"],
["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "NO", "6/29/2015 0:00", "6/29/2015 12:36"],
["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "yes", "8/31/2017 0:00", "8/31/2017 13:12"],
["62", "again", "someoneelse", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/30/2017 0:00", "1/30/2017 13:49"],

]
new_data = [(a, sorted([i[1:] for i in list(b)], key=lambda x:dateutil.parser.parse(x[-1]))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
final_data = [[a]+b[-1] for a, b in new_data]
for i in final_data:
   print(i)
```

Output:

```
['1', 'someone', 'cool', 'RO', 'AC', 'SKST', 'yes', '2/24/2017 0:00', '2/24/2017 10:51']
['102', 'another', 'person', 'RO', 'AC', 'SKST', 'yes', '8/31/2017 0:00', '8/31/2017 13:12']
['62', 'again', 'someoneelse', 'RO', 'AC', 'SKST', 'No', '1/30/2017 0:00', '1/30/2017 13:49']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want develop your own logic without importing any itertool module then you can try in pure python way :

Just an opinion:

I have added one more item with duplicate with two dates for test case :

```
data=[
    ["1", "someone", "cool", "RO",  "AC", "SKST", "yes", "2/24/2017 0:00", "2/24/2017 10:51"],
    ["1", "someone", "cool", "RO",  "AC", "SKST", "yes", "2/25/2017 0:00", "2/26/2017 10:51"],

    ["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/26/2015 15:54", "1/26/2015 15:54"],
    ["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "NO", "6/29/2015 0:00", "6/29/2015 12:36"],
    ["102", "another", "person", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "yes", "8/31/2017 0:00", "8/31/2017 13:12"],
    ["62", "again", "someoneelse", "RO", "AC", "SKST", "No", "1/30/2017 0:00", "1/30/2017 13:49"]
]
from operator import itemgetter

track=[]
no_duplicate=[]
duplicate_dict={}
for index,value in enumerate(data):
    if value[0] not in track:
        track.append(value[0])
        no_duplicate.append(value)
    else:
        if value[0] not in duplicate_dict:
            duplicate_dict[value[0]]=[data[index]]
            duplicate_dict[value[0]].extend([data[index-1]])

        else:
            duplicate_dict[value[0]].extend([data[index]])
            duplicate_dict[value[0]].extend([data[index - 1]])





for index,value in enumerate(no_duplicate):
    for item in [max(value,key=itemgetter(7))for key,value in duplicate_dict.items()]:
        if item[0] in value:
            no_duplicate[index]=item
print(no_duplicate)
```

output:

```
[['1', 'someone', 'cool', 'RO', 'AC', 'SKST', 'yes', '2/25/2017 0:00', '2/26/2017 10:51'], ['102', 'another', 'person', 'RO', 'AC', 'SKST', 'yes', '8/31/2017 0:00', '8/31/2017 13:12'], ['62', 'again', 'someoneelse', 'RO', 'AC', 'SKST', 'No', '1/30/2017 0:00', '1/30/2017 13:49']]
```